# jumbo frame + fine tune

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, hadoop

we have hadoop cluster ( machines are linux redhat 7 )  ,and we set jumbo frame according to documentation

first we set MTU=9000 on all nodes in the cluster

but we notice about some problems , so we decreased the value little until we have stable network

finally we get MTU=8850 , this value gives us stable network

we also configured the same MTU=8850 on all nodes and switches

***my question , is it ok to set diff value from MTU=9000 like MTU=8850*** ?

Comment: from my experience it really depend of your network configuration, some equipement will use different value as MTU, and on your machine this will depend of your linux release and your driver. So jumbo frame are tricky to setup, if you find a working MTU test it a lot and it should be good.

Comment: so according to your answer , I understand that I was doing the right things - to set MTU=8850 on all nodes & network components

Comment: Well to me jumbo frame has always been a bit strange in its setup, if you find value that work for you stick with it, but if you change your switchs or you operating system, this value could need some tuning. Jumbo frame is all about testing it, if it works. you should stick with the value you found IMHO. Some more opinion would be welcome though

Comment: do you think mix of some machine with MTU=9000 and some machines with MTU=8950 , is it OK ?

Comment: You'd want the values to be consistent, I wouldn't mix 9000 and 8950